# Fastest way to filter a jQuery selection's return array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, selector

**I am looking for a method to filter the return array of the jQuery selection.**

Let's say, I have the array of elements which is returned by jQuery:

```
window.elementSet = $("element");
```

Now, I would like to filter this array, to display only elements with "car" class, **without** redesigning the selector, so

<strike>`window.elementSetOfCars = $("element.car");`</strike>

As the returned value is an array of elements, we could just use .filter, or .grep, or a simple for / while loop, where we check each element's classes with .hasClass(), or attr("class"), or whatever.

What is the fastest method for this?

Comment: Why not benchmark it yourself? Use jsperf to test this out :-)

Comment: Thank You, I have to admit, I didn't know this site :)

- Still, I think, other may face this question, and find the answer helpful during coding as well.

Comment: As long as this filtering is just happening in memory, and if you don't have millions of elements, it shouldn't really matter as the speed difference will be negligable.

Comment: Not really, but it does, if many other functions are running simultaneously :)

Comment: I agree it's worth putting the question and answer up here, but I wanted to help you find your own answer. :-) By all means post your results here if you try it out. I put my reply as a comment because obviously it wasn't an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following :

```
var elementSetOf = window.elementSet.filter(function(val,i,arr){
return (val.className.indexOf('car') >= 0);
});
```

However, bear in mind that the result of $(selector) is actually not an array, but rather an "array-like" object, meaning a lot of Array methods & properties will work, but not all of them. [More info here](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects)

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work, but Steven asked about the *fastest* way to filter his data. So native JS will be faster than jQuery's `filter`. But as it has been pointed out, except in very special cases where you need to do this operation a zillion times, you won't notice the difference, whether other functions are running simultaneously or not.

EDIT : Somebody suggested to use `jQuery.filter` but deleted his comment. Doesn't make much sense now :/

Comment: Exactly, Waldo. However, window.elementSet.filter(".cars") would be the most developer-friendly solution here, but far not the fastest.